# Grouping Many Functions in Swift

Tags: swift

I've got a conceptual Animal API client class that will interface with a Rest Api below (it may have syntax errors, I'm typing it from my head).

```
class AnimalApi {   
  let connectionInfo: ApiConnectionInfo

  init(connectionInfo: ApiConnectionInfo) {
    self.connectionInfo = connectionInfo
  }

  func login(username: String, password: String) {
    // login stuff
  }

  func logout() {
    // logout stuff
  }

  func get(url: String) {

  }

  func post(url: String) {

  }

  func delete(url: String) {

  }
}

// Dogs
extension AnimalApi {
  func getAllDogs() -> Dogs {
    return get("dogResourceUrl")
  }
  func deleteDog() { }
  func updateDog() { }
}

// Cats
extension AnimalApi {
  func getAllCats() { }
  func deleteCat() { }
  func updateCat() { }
}
```

Is there a better way to group code in Swift instead of using extensions? There will be dozens of API resources I have to call that are all located on the same API server. I am trying to avoid the following...

```
let api = AnimalApi()
let dogs = api. // bombarded with all functions here, ideally something like api.Dogs.getAll would be more manageable
```

I realize that Apple uses extensions to group their code in their Swift API, but is there a better way? Sub classes maybe?

EDIT: I'd like to avoid sub classes if possible. This is because I am planning on having a single global instance of the AnimalApi since it will be accessed throughout the app constantly. Maybe make AnimalAPi members static and have separate classes with static members that contain functions that call the static AnimalApi.

```
class DogApi {
    class func all() { return AnimalApi.get("dogResourceUri") }
}

let dogs = DogApi.all()
```

Comment: What's the primary concern here?  Purely code organization?  Or is the "bombardment" of auto-complete functions the bigger concern?  Is there any reason you don't just subclass?  Assuming you know some other language, how would you tackle this problem in your "native" language?

Comment: The bombardment of auto complete functions is the biggest concern really. Extensions actually help organize the code pretty well as far as maintainability goes. In C# I would probably use subclases, but would want to avoid that if possible. I've added some more clarification to my question as well.

Comment: I tend to always write a service layer, to keep my otherwise independent model code clean - avoids the problem that you are having, and allows for cleaner separation.

Answer (score 3):

The below sample code is an attempt to accomplish your requirement.
Hope it helps.

```
typealias Task = () -> ()

typealias Api = (getAll: Task, delete: Task, update: Task)

class AnimalApi {

    let dogs: Api = {
        func getAll() { }
        func delete() { }
        func update() { }
        return (getAll, delete, update)
    }()

    let cats: Api = {
        func getAll() { }
        func delete() { }
        func update() { }
        return (getAll, delete, update)
    }()
}
```

Now you can use it anywhere in the app as follows without getting bombarded with all different functions:

```
let api = AnimalApi()
let dogs = api.dogs.getAll
```

Comment: could you explain why are the `Task` and `Api` type aliases required and how would it be if the functions (e.g. getAll) required some arguments to be passed?

Also, why do you have to return `(getAll, delete, update)`?
Thanks and sorry to bother you.